# Showing all forms

Tags: forms, solspace-freeform, solspace

I need to show all forms on one page dynamically.

I'm doing this:

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="one-of-my-forms"}
{freeform:all_form_fields}
    <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
    {freeform:field_output}
{/freeform:all_form_fields}
<p>{freeform:submit}</p>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

But as you can see, I've specified a form_name.

How do I get ALL forms without knowing how many there are..?

Comment: Is there a technical requirement to list all of the forms on one page? It sounds terribly inefficient. I think you might be better off using the freeform:form_info tag to list out your forms. Then open each form in their own page using the code you have above and replacing form_name with a segment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Freeform info tag pair, when used without a form_name or form_id param, outputs a list of the available forms. You may be able to use this loop to allow you to pull each form one after the other - with stash, you could stash the list of form IDs and then use them to output each form with its respective ID. Simplified view below:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="freeform_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:freeform:form_info}
        {stash:the_form_id}{freeform:form_id}{/stash:the_form_id}
    {/exp:freeform:form_info}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

And then later in the parse order:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="freeform_ids"}
    {exp:freeform:form form_id="{the_form_id}"}
        {freeform:all_form_fields}
            <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
            {freeform:field_output}
        {/freeform:all_form_fields}
        <p>{freeform:submit}</p>
    {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

That would output a "list" of your forms for each stashed form ID.

Comment: I get this error:

The following tag has a syntax error:

{exp:stash:set_list}

is Stash a plugin that google doesn't want to tell me about?

Comment: Ended up doing:
{exp:freeform:form_info}

 {exp:freeform:form form_name="{freeform:form_name}" form:id="ajax_form"} ..... Didn't use 'Stash'

Comment: Yes, sorry, stash is a free add-on available on devot-ee.com.